# Basic Authentication for Artifactory from PowerShell is throwing 403

Tags: powershell, artifactory, powershell-4.0, jfrog-cli

I am trying to authenticate to JFROG from powershell i tried it with my token and its giving 403 forbidden

```
  PS C:\Myproject> $myHeaders = @{'X-JFrog-Art-Api' = 'AKCp8sdFTEKF1Y5MDgM3M8RK6bRkKWoX43jWranZvS2U2DE82KFE7243F'}

  PS C:\Myproject> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://org.jfrog.io/" -Method Get -Headers $myHeaders

    Invoke-WebRequest : 403 Forbidden
    nginx
   At line:1 char:1
    + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://fiprod.jfrog.io/" -Method Get -Header ...
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any idea on how to authenticate to Artifactory via a token using PowerShell ?

Comment: Access tokens and API Keys are two different types of authenticators, and only API Keys work with the `X-JFrog-Art-Api` header. To pass an access token via a header, do: `$myHeaders = @{'Authorization' = "Bearer AKCp8sd..."}`

Comment: I tried  $sourceHeaders=@{
>>            'Authorization' = "Bearer $SOURCE_PASSWORD" }

Comment: i got  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $SOURCE_URL -Method POST -Headers $sourceHeaders
nginx
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $SOURCE_URL -Method POST -Headers $sourceHeade ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: I tried Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $SOURCE_URL -Method POST -Headers X-JFrog-Art-Api $sourceHeaders
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "X-JFrog-Art-Api" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:58

Comment: Again, _you cannot use **access tokens**_ with "X-JFrog-Art-Api" - it's only for authenticating with an API Key. Please [consult the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API)

Comment: can you please clarify more, if not access token i even tried with my own user and password, i still get the same error

Comment: Again, if you read the documentation, you'll see that you need to pass the credentials off differently based on type - if you're using username+password or username+access token => use Basic authentication. If you're using an API Key => use the `X-JFrog-Art-Api` header. If you're using just an access token => use `@{'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"}` as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still needed but maybe will help others. In most cases basic users cannot create an API key, leaving you with the only option of using only the token ID which needs to be used in correlation with your username.

Based on the official documentation https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-download-or-upload-a-file-from-to-artifactory-using-powershell/ , you have to create your header as follows:

```
-Headers @{ Authorization = "Basic "+ [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("USERNAME:PASSWORD")) }
```

where username is your JFrog artifactory username and the password is your authentication token.

As a good practice so you do not share sensitive information in your script you could add the user and token in your environment variables, and you can just read them from there in your script (assuming that having them as environment variables on your machines running the script is possible).

To use this approach you could do something like this:

```
$artifactoryUserName = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ARTIFACTORY_USER');
$artifactoryPassword = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD');
$artifactoryCredentials = $artifactoryUserName + ":" + $artifactoryPassword;
```

where ARTIFACTORY_USER and ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD are the environment variables holding the credentials for your JFrog artifactory and the $artifactoryCredentials variable is just creating the authentication string required by the authentication header format which you will incorporate in the header like this:

```
-Headers @{ Authorization = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($artifactoryCredentials)) }
```

or you can hold the entire authentication header in another variable.